# Spring Kafka - Consumer: Not receive message

Tags: spring-boot, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I am running kafka, zookeeper and kafdrop on docker using the below `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:6.0.2
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    volumes:
      - ~/.docker/data/zookeeper:/var/lib/zookeeper

  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.5.3
    hostname: kafka
    container_name: kafka
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: "${DOCKERHOST}"
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: "PLAINTEXT://${DOCKERHOST}:9092"
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "${DOCKERHOST}:2181"
      KAFKA_LOG_DIRS: /kafka/logs
      KAFKA_LOG_RETENTION_MINUTES: 10
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: "true"
      KAFKA_MESSAGE_MAX_BYTES: 4194304
      KAFKA_MAX_REQUEST_SIZE: 4194304
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    volumes:
      - ~/.docker/data/kafka/:/kafka/
    extra_hosts:
      - "dockerhost:$DOCKERHOST"

  kafdrop:
    image: obsidiandynamics/kafdrop
    container_name: kafdrop
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKERCONNECT: "kafka:9092"
    depends_on:
      - kafka
```

I have a Spring Boot Producer application with the below configuration - `KafkaTopicConfig.java`:

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaTopicConfig {

    @Value(value = "${kafka.bootstrapAddress}")
    private String bootstrapAddress;

    @Bean
    public KafkaAdmin kafkaAdmin() {
        Map<String, Object> configs = new HashMap<>();
        configs.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        return new KafkaAdmin(configs);
    }

}
```

And in my `KafkaProducerConfig.java` I have the following:

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaProducerConfig {

    @Value(value = "${kafka.bootstrapAddress}")
    private String bootstrapAddress;

    @Value(value = "${kafka.maxRequestSize}")
    private String maxRequestSize;

    @Value(value = "${kafka.batchSize}")
    private String batchSize;

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_REQUEST_SIZE_CONFIG, maxRequestSize);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG, batchSize);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.COMPRESSION_TYPE_CONFIG, "snappy");
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_BLOCK_MS_CONFIG, 120000);
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }
}
```

This is a separate application and I call the Kafka Producer like this in my service:

```
kafkaTemplate.send("test-topic-local", base64string);
```

In an all together different spring boot application, I have a consumer like this `KafkaConsumerConfig.java`:

```
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {

    @Value(value = "${kafka.bootstrapAddress}")
    private String bootstrapAddress;

    @Value(value = "${kafka.groupId}")
    private String groupId;

    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory(String groupId) {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, true);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
    }

    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(String groupId) {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory(groupId));
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> testKafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        return kafkaListenerContainerFactory(groupId);
    }

}
```

And in my service, I have a `KafkaListener` like below:

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class KafkaConsumerService {

    @KafkaListener(topics = "topic", containerFactory = "testKafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public void receive(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> consumerRecord) {
        log.info(consumerRecord.toString());
    }

}
```

I can see the consumer is being connected to the broker but there are logs for the message. Below is the full log I can see:

```
2021-03-08 17:15:20.218  INFO 4805 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8081 (http)
2021-03-08 17:15:20.237  INFO 4805 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-03-08 17:15:20.238  INFO 4805 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.43]
2021-03-08 17:15:20.362  INFO 4805 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[.[localhost].[/api/v1]        : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-03-08 17:15:20.362  INFO 4805 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2939 ms
2021-03-08 17:15:20.974  INFO 4805 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2021-03-08 17:15:21.210  INFO 4805 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.28.Final
2021-03-08 17:15:21.555  INFO 4805 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2021-03-08 17:15:21.792  INFO 4805 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-03-08 17:15:22.351  INFO 4805 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2021-03-08 17:15:22.410  INFO 4805 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
2021-03-08 17:15:22.938  INFO 4805 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2021-03-08 17:15:22.964  INFO 4805 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-03-08 17:15:23.125  WARN 4805 --- [  restartedMain] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2021-03-08 17:15:23.362  INFO 4805 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2021-03-08 17:15:24.007  INFO 4805 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2021-03-08 17:15:24.017  INFO 4805 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 2 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2021-03-08 17:15:24.208  INFO 4805 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.k.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig    : ConsumerConfig values: 
    allow.auto.create.topics = true
    auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
    auto.offset.reset = earliest
    bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092]
    check.crcs = true
    client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
    client.id = consumer-group-01-1
    client.rack = 
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
    enable.auto.commit = false
    exclude.internal.topics = true
    fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
    fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
    fetch.min.bytes = 1
    group.id = group-01
    group.instance.id = null
    heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
    interceptor.classes = []
    internal.leave.group.on.close = true
    internal.throw.on.fetch.stable.offset.unsupported = false
    isolation.level = read_uncommitted
    key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
    max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
    max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
    max.poll.records = 500
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partition.assignment.strategy = [class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
    receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    security.providers = null
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    session.timeout.ms = 10000
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    ssl.engine.factory.class = null
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLSv1.2
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer

2021-03-08 17:15:24.453  INFO 4805 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka version: 2.6.0
2021-03-08 17:15:24.454  INFO 4805 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka commitId: 62abe01bee039651
2021-03-08 17:15:24.454  INFO 4805 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka startTimeMs: 1615203924449
2021-03-08 17:15:24.459  INFO 4805 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer     : [Consumer clientId=consumer-group-01-1, groupId=group-01] Subscribed to topic(s): test-topic-local
2021-03-08 17:15:24.479  INFO 4805 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Initializing ExecutorService
2021-03-08 17:15:24.538  INFO 4805 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8081 (http) with context path '/api/v1'
2021-03-08 17:15:24.572  INFO 4805 --- [  restartedMain] c.r.i.t.m.f.FeedConsumerApplication      : Started FeedConsumerApplication in 7.929 seconds (JVM running for 8.652)
2021-03-08 17:15:25.302  INFO 4805 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata        : [Consumer clientId=consumer-group-01-1, groupId=group-01] Cluster ID: fq0PTZmwTnKQcCtUDMiQBg
```

Answer (score 0):

In your sender you have ,`kafkaTemplate.send("topic", base64string);`  , where basically you are publishing to topic -> "topic" , but your consumer is subscribed to `topic -> "test-topic-local"`  [That is from the logs you provided.]  Make sure your consumer is listening to the topic you are producing.

Comment: actually I edited that so as to not reveal the topic name but both are listening to same topic only updated my question now

Comment: If that's the complete log, you are not getting any assigned partitions; try DEBUG logging for `org.apache.kafka` to see if it provides more clues.

Comment: Doesn't the log say `Subscribed to topic(s): test-topic-local` which means it got attached to the topic actually??

Comment: @gary Russell can you please share what I need to modify in order to get this working and also some docs on why it is needed?

Comment: As I said, we need to see a DEBUG log for the kafka clients - that log just means subscription is initiated; if it is successful, you will see `2021-03-08 15:35:44.890  INFO 73786 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] s.k.l.ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer : ktest27int: partitions assigned: [ktest27-1, ktest27-0, ktest27-3, ktest27-2, ktest27-9, ktest27-8, ktest27-5, ktest27-4, ktest27-7, ktest27-6]` (in this case I subscribed to a topic with 10 partitions). Refer to your logging subsystem documentation to enable DEBUG logging.

Comment: @GaryRussell I tried TRACE for org.springframework.kafka and this is the log I can get - https://pastebin.com/T2sDyJAk. I cant see any partition being assigned. I have tried doing via `@KafkaListener(id = "foo", topicPartitions = { @TopicPartition(topic = "test-topic-local", partitions = { "0" })})` as mine topic is 1 partition only but still same result

Comment: I said you need to DEBUG `org.apache.kafka`, not Spring. Here's the smoking gun `org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout of 60000ms expired before the position for partition test-topic-local-0 could be determined`.

Comment: Yes, after increasing the request timeout it has started to work as expected